# load page only when there is a change in database using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery

Please is there any way to check if there is a change in database and fetch to page only when a change is made in the database. When i say change i mean add, update and delete. And also without setting interval every x second because each time i try to highlight and the x second is reach it clean out what i highlighted.Please i need your help.
below is the code i am using

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        done();
    });
    function done(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            done();
            update();
        },200);
    }
    function update(){
        $("#display").load("profile_status_update.php");
    }
```

Comment: let jquery check your database every so much of time whether the values have changed since the last check

Comment: Do a research for "ajax long poll", that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Look into websockets. It's heavy stuff, but it's the only way to get notified of changes on the server without ajax polling.